# Compile selinux in private directory

Tags: selinux, seafile-server, libselinux

I'm trying to compile selinux in a private directory as drescribed here:
https://github.com/SELinuxProject/selinux

For the compilation to work I also compiled xmlto and added it's bin-dir to $PATH.

The compilation fails with the following lines.

```
xmlto man secilc.8.xml
xmlto: /opt/seafile/Sourcecode/selinux/secilc/secilc.8.xml does not validate (status 3)
xmlto: Fix document syntax or use --skip-validation option
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.2/docbookx.dtd
/opt/seafile/Sourcecode/selinux/secilc/secilc.8.xml:3: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.2/docbookx.dtd"
               "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.2/docbookx.dtd">
                                                                        ^
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.2/docbookx.dtd
warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.2/docbookx.dtd"
validity error : Could not load the external subset "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.2/docbookx.dtd"
Document /opt/seafile/Sourcecode/selinux/secilc/secilc.8.xml does not validate
make[1]: *** [Makefile:36: secilc.8] Fehler 13
make[1]: Verzeichnis „/opt/seafile/Sourcecode/selinux/secilc“ wird verlassen
make: *** [Makefile:34: install] Fehler 1
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Can I somehow tell make not to build the documentation? Seem's to be a manpages thing.

Additional info: I actually only need libselinux since It's required by seafile for some reason.

Thanks in advance

Markus

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you're not mentioning the Linux distribution you're using. Your system is missing the "XML document type definitions for DocBook", often shipped in a package called `docbook-dtds` (Fedora, RHEL/CentOS) or `docbook-xml` (Debian). Alternatively you could adapt your packet filter so that your system reaches the mentioned URLs in the error message.